# Integrating React-Native and TesseractOCR

Tags: xcode, react-native, tesseract

I am attempting to integrate the TesseractOCRiOS package as part of the implementation of the react-native-text-detector package (https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector).  However, I am unable to compile under iOS, it fails with a **'TesseractOCR/TesseractOCR.h' file not found** error.

I can see TesseractOCR in my Pods directory in Xcode but it does not follow the normal packaging convention.  By this I mean, normally, I see a *.framework package within the directory but not in this case.  I see the TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR directory and within there, the *.h header files, *.m implementation files and lib/include directories.

I tried attempting to reference the header files through the Build Settings/Header Search Paths but that did not work.  Thoughts on what you need to do in XCode to find the necessary header files?